# How to convert Gregorian date to Hijri (Islamic) date in Fast Report

Tags: date, fastreport, hijri

I use a program that uses Fast Report in reporting the problem is that fast Report converts Hijri date to Gregorian date , although the settings of Windows is the Hijri date

Answer (score 0):

Check out these links may be helpful

[Cannot convert from Hijri Date to Gregorian date (c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189807/cannot-convert-from-hijri-date-to-gregorian-date-c)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/f2e7ec6a-a76a-4229-97d1-8505094a2657/wrong-date-in-converting-gregorian-to-hijri-calendar

http://www.islamicfinder.org/dateConversion.php