# How to determine upcoming months relative to a given month in any calendar?

Tags: c#, datetime, calendar, globalization

How can I find out the upcoming months relative to a given month according to the calendar that I select?

Meaning I selected the Gregorian calendar and the given month is September, a list of the following months will appear:

[September, October, November, December]

If the Hijri calendar is selected and the current month is: Dhu al-Qa’dah, a list of the remaining months will appear, which are:

[Dhul Qi'dah, Dhul Hijjah]

I used the following reference to make the code but it didn't work

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo(DateLangCulture, false).DateTimeFormat
```

Comment: Maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11189807/14171304

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET Framework, month names are based on a culture. If I understand your question clearly, you wanna select some "Calendar" and wanna list some months of it. I think there is a problem with this approach because different cultures might use the same calendar and these different cultures might have different month names.

For example, let's take [`GregorianCalendar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.gregoriancalendar?view=net-6.0), if you wanna list *english-based* month names, you can clearly use a culture like [`InvariantCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=net-6.0) which you will get `January`, `February`, `March` etc.. But on the other side, Turkish culture (`tr-TR`) also uses `GregorianCalendar` as a calendar but it's month names are like `Ocak`, `Şubat`, `Mart` etc. That means, even if you choose a "right" [`CultureInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-6.0) for your calendar, you might have a language problem as well. I hope you understand my concern. A calendar months *might* have a different languages since they are belongs on cultures.

If you really wanna get these based on calendars, you can create a `CultureInfo` which uses selected `Calendar` and list their [`MonthNames`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames?view=net-6.0) property as a string array which starts with the current month.

For example; for `GregorianCalendar`, you can use `InvariantCulture` which month names are;

```
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames
```

January
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
September
October
November
December

and for `HijriCalendar`, you can use `ar-SA` culture (it uses `UmAlQuraCalendar` which is close enough to `HijriCalendar` in my opinion) which month names are;

```
(new CultureInfo("ar-SA")).DateTimeFormat.MonthNames
```

محرم
صفر
ربيع الأول
ربيع الآخر
جمادى الأولى
جمادى الآخرة
رجب
شعبان
رمضان
شوال
ذو القعدة
ذو الحجة

which they can be translated to English as;

[image]

You can get the current month number as;

```
var currentMonthNo = Datetime.Now.Month;
```

then you can start to iterate from it's previous index (since array start index 0) to the end of the array (*Be aware*, there are some calendars that have 13 months, that's why for 12 month cultures  the 13th element of the array is an empty string.)

Comment: Suppose the client machine has a Hijri calendar, and I just want to use only the Gregorian calendar, and I want to extract the names of the months with the month number in a dropdown only

Comment: @ebrahemb Then you have to check first which calendar that client uses and after it, create a `CultureInfo` that corresponds with _that_ calendar and iterate the `MonthNames` propert starting with the current month number which always you can get using `Datetime.Now.Month` for gregorian calendar. Have you ever tried to code it? Sounds like you only asking for theoretical implementation instead of _actually_ implement it.

Answer (score 0):

### Only supplement Soner Gönül's answer.

#### If you want to get the Gregorian calendar month according to the current system calendar, you can refer to the following code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1 {
    internal class Program {
        static void Main (string[] args) {
            //CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
            //CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar-SA");
            CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr");
            List<KeyValuePair<int,string>> months = new List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>();
            for (int i = getCurMonth(); i <= 12; i++)
                {
                months.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(i, DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "-" + i + "-1").ToString("MMMM", culture)));
                }
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> month in months)
                {
                Console.WriteLine(month.Value);
                }
            Console.ReadLine();
            }
        static int getCurMonth () {
            return DateTime.Now.Month;
            }
        }
    }
```

#### To obtain a specific country calendar, the system must install the corresponding character set.

You can see the following example:

##### en-us

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
```

Output:

[image]

##### fr

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr")
```

Output:

[image]

If you have questions about my code, please comment below.